# how to display an element of parent in iframe

Tags: iframe

newbie question

I have a multiselect box that i populate with some ajax and shape with some jquery.SO i dont want to repeat all these operations whenever an iframe shows up. 
is it possible to reuse it ? ?

Comment: why do you use an iframe? you could also use .laod()? well create a function for it? and throw away these iframes

Comment: i have an iframe that opens a page for some forms . i need the same multiselect in those form pages. im using modal "colorbox"

Comment: is it a page on your server? you cant normally access the iframe content with javascript, you should use a div and jquery .laod()

Comment: yes its a page on my server. i show the page in an iframe with a jquery plugin called "colorbox" .

Comment: there are better colorbox alternatives like shadowbox, but i recommend you use .load() instead of an iframe so you can access the content with .live() and some other functions in jquery

Comment: shadowbox is not free commercially. anyway. what i did at last is, putting all data i need into variables and shaping the element with that data from "parent". at least i saved some webservice connection

Comment: that was an example  there are also other ones

Comment: thank you mate. you wouldve been helpful but i failed big time on explaining what i need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has been an old question but i wanted to answer as it may help someone someday.

To avoid all the repeating Ajax calls , i just saved the data in objects ,then access the data from iframe to draw my elements.